# net/http PUT with body causes problems

Tags: ruby, curl, net-http

I want to use the Cloudera API from ruby. Therefore I want to
update the configuration of the cloudera manager, which is done
with an HTTP PUT request containing some json data.

The URL is `http://localhost:7180/api/v11/cm/config`, my first approach was the following code:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'base64'

port = 7180
host = 'localhost'

req = Net::HTTP::Put.new('/api/v11/cm/config')
req.body = '{"items":[{"name":"TSQUERY_STREAMS_LIMIT","value":1000},{"name":"parcel_proxy_server","value":"proxy"},{"name":"parcel_proxy_port","value":"8080"},{"name":"parcel_update_freq","value":"1"}]}'
req['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
req['Authorization'] = "Basic #{Base64.encode64('admin:admin')}"

client = Net::HTTP.new(host, port)
resp = client.request(req)

puts resp
puts resp.to_hash
puts resp.body
```

This variant returns a 400 Bad Request response with the message
`"message" : "No content to map due to end-of-input\n at [Source: org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination$1@4561cbc9; line: 1, column: 1]"`

If I want to trace this in wireshark with the setting `tcp.port == 7180`, this request does somehow not show up.

Then I switched to using `Net::HTTP.start` with the following source code:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'base64'

port = 7180
host = 'localhost'

req = Net::HTTP::Put.new('/api/v11/cm/config')
req.body = '{"items":[{"name":"TSQUERY_STREAMS_LIMIT","value":1000},{"name":"parcel_proxy_server","value":"proxy"},{"name":"parcel_proxy_port","value":"8080"},{"name":"parcel_update_freq","value":"1"}]}'
req['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
req['Authorization'] = "Basic #{Base64.encode64('admin:admin')}"

resp = Net::HTTP.start(host, port) { |client| client.request(req) }

puts resp
puts resp.to_hash
puts resp.body
```

This thing also returned a bad request, but without any body or else. In contrast to the first approach, this one showed up in wireshark but the body it posted was depicted as with Hypertext-Transfer-Protocol. If I do the same request with cURL, the request body is correctly shown as JavaScript Object Notation.

Does anybody know what the problem of my requests is?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I tried around for several hours but this behavior is rather strange:

To resolve this I first used `Net::HTTP.start` instead of `Net::HTTP.new`. Second and even more important:
I used to do basic authentication by setting the header value manually as you could see in

```
req['Authorization'] = "Basic #{Base64.encode64('admin:admin')}"
```

But `Net::HTTP::Put` already provides a `basic_auth` method. If this one is not used, strange errors as the ones that I got will occur.

So the working version looks like this:

```
req = Net::HTTP::Put.new('/api/v11/cm/config')
req.body = '{"items":[{"name":"TSQUERY_STREAMS_LIMIT","value":1000},{"name":"parcel_proxy_server","value":"proxy"},{"name":"parcel_proxy_port","value":"8080"},{"name":"parcel_update_freq","value":"1"}]}'
req['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
req.basic_auth 'admin', 'admin'

resp = Net::HTTP.start(host, port) { |client| client.request(req) }
```